# listen to events on the client side only when a change has occurred Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there some way to use a listener that listens for changes on the server and sends the changes to UI as soon as those changes happen? I'm using a websocket (singalr package to be exact) and I need to set up an event listener so that the client side captures all changes. I read that I need to use streams instead of futures and I can also subscribe to the event there, but is this suitable for the application to poll the server every time only when it actually changes, and not constantly? For example, I read that in a java script, you can use an event listener that independently "understand" that changes have occurred on the server side and pass them on to the frontend side (I am not a JS developer, but I have heard that JS has such functionality, so if there is something like this in Dart?). Right now I'm using the following code, but I'm not sure if it does exactly what I described

```
static Stream<String?> getData() =>
      Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1)).asyncMap((event) => fetchData());


  static Future<String?> fetchData() async {
    final hubConnection =
        HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('https://secure/secure').build();
    await hubConnection.start();
    String? values;

    if (hubConnection.state == HubConnectionState.Connected) {
      await hubConnection
          .invoke('GetData')
          .then((value) => values= value as String);
    }
    print('values');
    hubConnection.onclose(({error}) {
      throw Exception(error);
    });
    print(values);
    return values;
  }
```